# Can't set keyboard focus to ScrollViewer in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a control with a button and scrollviewer next to it. I want to be able to change keyboard focus via arrow keys or the tab key. I've set scrollviewer's focusable to true, but it seems it still cannot gain focus via keyboard. If I click on the scrollviewer then I can scroll using the arrow keys (up/down), but I cannot actually navigate to it without using the mouse.

I can focus on the button fine and if I change the scrollviewer for another control (in the same position) such as ScrollContentPresenter then the other control can switch focus between itself and the button as I would expect.

I am trying to understand why ScrollViewer cannot gain focus here. All search results I have found have the reverse problem (ScrollViewer stealing focus). Also if I set focusable to true on a control inside the ScrollViewer then it can gain focus as well. It just seems to be impossible for ScrollViewer to gain focus.

Here's the code sample with commented out ScrollContentPresenter (which can gain focus when used to replace ScrollViewer).

```
<Grid >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Height="50" Width="300" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyleLol}" />
        <ScrollViewer Height="200" Width="1300"  Focusable="True">
            <StackPanel Height="1000" >
                <StackPanel.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF71E1E" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </StackPanel.Background>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <!--<ScrollContentPresenter Height="200" Width="1300"  Focusable="True">
            <ScrollContentPresenter.Content>
                <StackPanel Height="1000">
                    <StackPanel.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="Black"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFF71E1E" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </StackPanel.Background>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollContentPresenter.Content>
        </ScrollContentPresenter>-->
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `IsTabStop` property of the `ScrollViewer` to `true` seems to work for me:

```
<ScrollViewer IsTabStop="True" Focusable="True">
```

Comment: That did help both with the tab key and arrow keys. Could someone explain why IsTabStop property changed the arrow keys behaviour? It was my understanding that it should only change tab key behaviour?

Comment: Why? Because of the internal implementation.